# vim's vimrc messes up vim completely

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, vimrc, manjaro

i am using manjaro linux, and i installed vim using

```
$ sudo pacman -S vim
```

then i modified my vimrc file

```
$ sudo vim /etc/vimrc
```

then i added some cool things:

```
set background="dark"
set number
set shiftwidth=2
set scrolloff=5
set autoindent
```

but when i try to edit another file, the line numbers have been indented, and the bottom panel where it tells me if im in insert mode doesn't work, and backspace does not work even in insert mode, hope someone can help me. thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

> then i modified my vimrc file

No. That file is *not* your vimrc file.

Remove everything you have added to `/etc/vimrc` and put it in *your* `~/.vimrc`.

Since we are at it,

- you don't need to quote "dark" (which doesn't do what you probably think it does anyway),
- none of those settings have any effect on showing the current mode or the behavior of `<Backspace>`.

Comment: Why is that? I use `/etc/vimrc` as a global config file because I want the settings for every user. I see no problem using this as config file as long as `~/.vimrc` has the line `source /etc/vimrc`.

Comment: @ap0, but you are not the OP, right? As an admin you want all your users to have the same settings, as the single user of his own machine he only wants *himself* to have his own settings.

Comment: I am also a single user. By "all users" I ment my default account and root. I only wanted to point out that it is ok to use the global vimrc. In your post it felt a little bit that you discourage using that file. But maybe this is a matter of opinion. :)